# What else capabilities need to enable in order to use "form_factor"

Tags: wurfl

I am using WURFL, in order to detect `form_factor`

I enable the following capability.

```
- "form_factor"
```

However, once I run the code to detect `form_factor`, it crashes.

Then, when I look at source code

```
wurfl/wurfl-api/WURFL/VirtualCapability/IsSmartphone.php
wurfl/wurfl-api/WURFL/VirtualCapability/FormFactor.php
```

I realize I need to enable rest of the capabilities.

```
- "ux_full_desktop"
- "is_smarttv"
- "is_wireless_device"
- "is_tablet"

- "pointing_method"
- "resolution_width"
- "device_os_version"
- "device_os"
- "can_assign_phone_number"
```

I was wondering, is this the complete list of capabilities which required, in order to support `form_factor`?

As I don't find any detailed documentation (https://www.scientiamobile.com/wurflCapability) regarding `form_factor`.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Luca Passani, CTO @Scientiamobile. The company that produces WURFL and all WURFL APIs.

WURFL Users have access to support, so I invite you to reach out to ScientiaMobile through teh regular support channels.

Please make sure that you provide complete information about the API version you are using.